# Making Attoparsec based parser more efficient

Tags: parsing, haskell, attoparsec

I wrote a simple text STL (Standard Tessellation Library) parser using Attoparsec. STL contains a collection of facets. Each facet contains a normal, and vertices of triangle. Typical STL file can be large (~100 Mb or more).

STL file format is

```
solid
 facet normal nx ny nz
   outer loop
       vertex x1 y1 z1
       vertex x2 y2 z2
       vertex x3 y3 z3 
 endfacet
endsolid
```

The parser code is here. Full implementation can be found at [STLReader](https://gist.github.com/yogeshsajanikar/0230c50d76dc3caa7193)

```
-- | Point represents a vertex of the triangle
data Point a = Point !a !a !a deriving Show

-- | Vector for a given class
data Vector a = Vector !a !a !a deriving Show

-- | Parse coordinate triplet. 
coordinates :: (Fractional a) => Text -> (a -> a -> a -> b) -> Parser b
coordinates s f = do
  skipSpace
  string s
  !x <- coordinate
  !y <- coordinate
  !z <- coordinate
  return $! f x y z
  where
    coordinate = skipWhile isHorizontalSpace *> fmap realToFrac double
{-# INLINE coordinates #-}

type RawFacet a = (Vector a, Point a, Point a, Point a)

-- | Parse a facet. The facet comprises of a normal, and three vertices
facet  :: Fractional a => Parser (RawFacet a)
facet = (,,,) <$> beginFacet
          <* (skipSpace     *> "outer loop")
          <*> vertexPoint
          <*> vertexPoint
          <*> vertexPoint
          <*  (skipSpace <* "endloop" <* endFacet )
          <?> "facet"
  where
    beginFacet  = skipSpace <* "facet" *> coordinates "normal" Vector
    endFacet    = skipSpace <* string "endfacet"
    vertexPoint = coordinates "vertex" Point
{-# INLINE facet #-}

rawFacets :: Fractional a => Parser [RawFacet a]
rawFacets = beginSolid *> many' facet <* endSolid
      where
            solidName  = option "default" (skipWhile isHorizontalSpace *> fmap T.pack (many1 $ satisfy isAlphaNum) )
            beginSolid = skipSpace <* "solid" *> solidName <?> "start solid"
            endSolid   = skipSpace <* "endsolid" <?> "end solid"

-- | Read text STL file. STL extensions for color etc. are not supported in this version. 
readTextSTL :: Fractional a => FilePath -> IO (Either String [RawFacet a])
readTextSTL path = liftM (Al.eitherResult . Al.parse rawFacets) (TIO.readFile path)

main :: IO Int
main = do
  (path:_) <- getArgs
  putStrLn $ "Parsing STL file: " ++ path
  s <- readTextSTL path
  putStrLn "Parsing complete"
  case s of
   Left error -> putStrLn error
   Right s    -> putStrLn $ "Num facets : " ++ show (length s)
  return 0
```

I benchmarked this code with 'c' parser supplied with [Meshlab](http://meshlab.sourceforge.net/). When I tested with 69Mb scan, meshlab completed the job in roughly 13 s, whereas it took 22 s with attoparsec. So though attoparsec enabled me to parse faster than Parsec (with parsec it was about 36 s), I still have a long way to go.

How can I improve this parser further?

Comment: Can you share the test STL file?

Comment: You can download the test file from http://www.thingiverse.com/download:1962. This is a part of "human brain" (http://www.thingiverse.com/thing:822) collection.

Comment: Did you profile your code yet? What optimizations flags did you use? Where is most of the time spent?

Comment: I profiled program, and optimized to an extent. First gain was achieved by using 'double' rather than `rational` as suggested by attoparsec documentation. Second gain was achieved by making `coordinates` parser strict. In the current version, coordinates.coordinate takes (and understandable) most time amounting to 73% of time (and 71% allocation). And it is at this point, I am looking forward to make it more efficient. The actual cabal package is at github (https://github.com/yogeshsajanikar/stl)

Comment: Shifting to ByteString from Text put me near desired performance. This stackoverflow question (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5971855/when-do-i-use-bytestring-and-when-do-i-not) also helped.